# How to find unread message in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

[image]

I got 3 unread message in outlook. How do I find those 3 unread message so I can either read that or delete

Inbox has 100k messages. Scrolling them would be inpractical..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the `Search Inbox` (depends on the currently opened folder) or on the blue magnifier (Ctrl+E shortcut), then filter by `Unread`.

[image: Find unread emails]

Answer (score 0):

"You can find your unread messages in the Unread Mail folder under Search Folders in the Navigation Pane, where the unread messages are arranged by folder."

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/find-all-my-unread-messages-HA010118513.aspx

This describes how to restore the Unread Mail folder if it is missing.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/restore-the-unread-mail-folder-HA010355884.aspx